# Can I do STI and still use polymorphic path helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Single Table Inheritance and have comments on all the subclasses. I am only using 1 controller for all the different STI types. When the form_for helper generates a URL for a subtype it tries to use a helper for the subtype, but I want it to use the helper for the parent.

This is the error I get:

```
undefined method `subclasstypename_comments_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x41ef27c>
```

The path helper it 'should' use is

```
parentclasstypename_comments_path
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Yep, just use `AR::Base#becomes`.

Say your base class is `Account`, which is subclassed to `GuestAccount` and `LoginAccount`.

```
@account.is_a? LoginAccount? #=> true
```

Then you can just do a

```
form_for [@account.becomes(Account), @comment] do |f|
  ...
```

Comment: the form renders correctly with correct path but nothing gets saved when I submit the form

Comment: this is utterly awesome.

Comment: Link to documentation -> [ActiveRecord::Base.becomes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes)

Comment: Since the link to Henrik's blog post isn't working anymore, I just want to reiterate that this has some issues. If you have an object with associated has_many children, the validations and error messages are lost when you call the new object in the form.

Comment: Working link to Henrik's post: http://thepugautomatic.com/2012/08/rails-sti-and-form-for/