# How do I force Rails to use the superclass name in link_to helpers when using STI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, single-table-inheritance

I'm using STI with a Rails 3.2 app. I want to force Rails to use the superclass name in `link_to` helpers (or any where else when it's generating paths) and not the subclass name.

So, `<%= link_to current_user.name, current_user %>` produces `/:class_name/:id` (class name can be "Moderator," "Member," etc...).

I would like it to produce `/users/:id`, where `users` does not change to the name of the subclass. I know I can change `current_user` to `user_path(current_user)`, but I prefer to use the shortcut, letting Rails figure it out.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should define url helpers, something like this

```
def moderator_url record
  user_url record
end
```

Or just use aliases

```
alias :moderator_url :user_url
```

This is code which rails use for url generation when you pass a record as a option

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/537ede912895d421b24acfcbc86daf08f8f22157/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb#L90

Comment: Can't find anything in `alias` ... can you point me to anything?

Comment: I honestly don't see the need to alias at this point. Why bother when `resources :owners, path: 'users', controller: 'users'` solves the problem?

Comment: Because this is answer to you question, how to avoid using helpers directly. And why `owners`? Why not `resources :users`?

Comment: There is [a more complete answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507149/best-practices-to-handle-routes-for-sti-subclasses-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

For links, I can get around this by adding a resource:

```
resources :owners, path: 'users', controller: 'users'
```

For forms, I need to specify generic form. My initial form was

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
```

To make this work, I had to specify the path and the method, while using a generic name instead of passing the user object to the form directly:

```
= simple_form_for :user, url: user_path(@user) do |f|
```

Comment: but this is not answer to your question. Just read source code of rails and look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Use the named route:

```
<%= link_to current_user.name, user_path(current_user) %>
```

Comment: I said in my question that I prefer not to use a named route.