# STI with many types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sti

I have a rails 4 app with STI models:

```rb
# models/person.rb
def Person < ActiveRecord::Base

end

# models/director.rb
def Director < Person

end

# models/actor.rb
def Director < Person

end
```

But because one person can be an actor and an director simultaneously, I want STI with many types like:

```rb
person = Person.first
person.type = "Director, Actor"
person.save

Actor.first.id => 1

Director.first.id => 1
```

Is there mechanism in rails or gem for realize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to all answerers above!

I found solution that most appropriate for me:
I've created hmt association Person-ProfessionsPerson-Profession and leave descendants for Person class (Director and Actor).

```rb
# models/profession.rb
Profession < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :professions_people, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :people, through: :professions_people
end

# models/person.rb
def Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :professions_people, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :professions, through: :professions_people
end

# models/director.rb
def Director < Person
  include PeopleFromProfession
end

# models/actor.rb
def Actor < Person
  include PeopleFromProfession
end
```

I've seed 2 professions with column "class_type" (which should not change in app's work) "Actor" and "Director"
I've also add concern PeopleFromProfession for share some code:

```rb
# models/concerns/actor.rb
module PeopleFromProfession
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    default_scope { includes(:professions).where(professions: {class_type: self.name}) }

    after_create :create_join_table_record
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def model_name
      Person.model_name
    end
  end

private
  def create_join_table_record
    self.professions << Profession.where(class_type: self.class.name).first
  end

end
```

default_scope is for scoping only people with specific profession, create_join_table_record callback is monkey-patch for create missed join table record.

Class method model_name was overwriting for purposes, that covered here [Best practices to handle routes for STI subclasses in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507149/best-practices-to-handle-routes-for-sti-subclasses-in-rails)

If you will find some problems in that approach, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Rails does not support this and I'm not aware of any gems that support this as described (i.e. multiple subclass names in the type column).

There is gem at https://github.com/mhuggins/multiple_table_inheritance which uses separate tables for the subclasses and you can always use mixins as an alternative to inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the more Rails idiomatic way to do something similar would be via `scopes`, which would allow you to do:

```
person = Person.first
person.position = 'Director, Actor'
person.save

person.directors.first.id => 1
person.actors.first.id => 1
```

And you would just have to define a pair of scopes in your `Person` class:

```
scope :actors, -> { where('position like ?', '%Actor%') }
scope :directors, -> { where('position like ?', '%Director%') }
```

You would lose the ability to do `person.is_a?` with this, but Ruby doesn't really do multiple inheritance in such a way as to allow `#is_a?` to return true when passed sibling classes anyway. You can also get effectively similar functionality with a simple test method:

```
def is_actor?
    self.position =~ /Actor/
end
def is_director?
    self.position =~ /Director/
end
```

EDIT: I haven't done a lot of Rails 4, so my `scope` syntax MAY not be right, I just glanced at the docs. The principle should be sound, though.