# Is there a simpler way than using STI or polymorphic associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-table-inheritance

I have been reading a lot on the difference between STI and polymorphic associations and decided to use STI:

```
user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :articles
end

article.rb
Class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :users
end

sport.rb
Class Sport < Article
end

politic.rb
Class Politic < Article
end

food.rb
Class Food < Article
end

create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.string   "artwork"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
t.boolean  "approved",   default: false
t.string   "type"
```

However, upon further [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507149/best-practices-to-handle-routes-for-sti-subclasses-in-rails?rq=1), this becomes even more complicated. All I am really looking to do is to find some way to sort my articles by type. For example, is it possible that I simply have a `string column tag` and specify that tag must be either `politics, sports, or food`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, use an [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum article_type: [:sport, :politic, :food] #-> "article_type" (int) column required
end
```

The only drawback to this would be that you can only assign *one* enum value to your model; from the use case you've outlined, it seems that's what you need.

---

The `enum` will allow you to use the following:

```
@article = Article.find params[:id]

@article.sport?    #-> true
@article.politic?  #-> false
@article.food?     #-> false

@article.profile_type #-> "sport"
```

You also get a set of `class methods` to identify the various objects you need from the db:

```
@sports_articles = Article.sport #-> collection of "sport" articles
```

---

To create an `@article` through a form, you'll need [`collection_select`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_select):

```
#app/views/articles/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :profile_type, Article.profile_types, :first, :first %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

**Update**

Pagination occurs on data **received** from the db.

Thus, if you wanted to "include" data in the pagination, you'd just have to make sure you're pulling it from the db. To do this, you'd need to include as many `article_types` as you want:

```
#app/models/article.rb
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
   scope :by_type, (types) -> { where(article_type: Array.new(types)) }
end
```

This will allow you to use the following:

```
@articles = Article.by_type(:sport, :politic).paginate(page: params [:page], per_page: 12)
```

As per the [docs](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

```
Conversation.where(status: [:active, :archived])
```

Comment: How can I setup a form to accept an enum value when I build @article?

Comment: You can use a `collection_select`, I'll update the answer

Comment: Is it supposed to be [ :sport, :politic, :food ] ? Other tutorials show it that way.

Comment: Are you Rich of richonrails.com?

Comment: how can i setup the controller if i want to paginate all of the `@article.sport` and all of the `@article.food` using `<% @articles.in_groups_of(6, false).each do |group| %>` in index.html.erb. For example, I currently have `@articles = Article.sport.all.paginate(page: params [:page], per_page: 12)` but I also want to show `Article.food` in the same pagination.

Comment: I am trying to write a scope perhaps.

Comment: Updated answer with the above

Comment: How do you know to get from what is listed in the docs (which I read) to that code? It doesn't seem intuitive to me (noob).

Comment: The docs are reference material. You cannot infer entire structural patterns from the documentation, just how specific functionality works. If you know how different functions work together, you can piece them together to get a workable solution

Comment: The accumulated knowledge behind a recommendation on here is built from 10+ years of heavy computer usage; 3 years professional software development. One of the reasons I spend a long time on here is so I can keep my skills sharp, knowing how different aspects of the system work