# Single Table Inheritance sharing the same model name: how to translate the model name of derived classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, single-table-inheritance

I have an abstract class `WcagElement`, and several derived classes that share the same model name so I can share the views, routes, etc. between all of them:

```
class WcagElement < ApplicationRecord
  # See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507149/best-practices-to-handle-routes-for-sti-subclasses-in-rails/13131811
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, 'WcagElement') # Make sure that STI models use the same namespace
  end
end

class WcagPrinciple < WcagElement
end

class WcagGuideline < WcagElement
end

class WcagCriterion < WcagElement
end
```

This works very well.

The only problem I have is that in some views, I need to display the translated human model name of a derived class.

At the time, because I override `self.model_name` in the abstract class, I get the same model name for each model:

```
$ WcagPrinciple.model_name.human => WCAG Element
$ WcagGuideline.model_name.human => WCAG Element
$ WcagCriterion.model_name.human => WCAG Element
```

I have added the relevant keys to the translation file:

```
wcag_criterion:
  one: Criterion
  other: Criteria
wcag_element:
  one: WCAG element
  other: WCAG elements
wcag_guideline:
  one: Guideline
  other: Guideline
wcag_principle:
  one: Principle
  other: Principles
```

I tried messing around with creating a `sti_model_name` method:

```
# In WcagPrinciple
def sti_model_name # Or better self.sti_model_name?
  ActiveModel::Name.new(self, nil, 'WcagPrinciple')
end
```

But `$ WcagPrinciple.sti_model_name.human` results in `Wcag principle` (instead of `WCAG Principle`), which is a generically created human name, not the one in the translation file.

I also tried to `alias` the old `self.model_name`, but didn't succeed.

Thanks for help.